# Cannot read from text file using readlines() method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used to be able to perform file io operations on plain text files using python 3, however a few days ago I encountered errors whenever I tried to use the `readlines()` method on plain text files.

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
>       return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I get this above error message whenever I try to use the `readlines()` method, previously it worked as it was supposed to.

Comment: Does the file you are trying to read contain non-ascii characters? Thats what the error is saying

Comment: Do you have an example of your code with context?

Comment: It looks like you're somehow trying to use the ascii encoding to read a non-ascii file. Just read it as-is and python-3 should use the 'utf-8' encoding by default

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the encoding when opening the file?

```
with open('file', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
      ...
```